# C# Picture Box Label Show

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

In Visual Studio,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRPK6.png) I want to add a picture box which when empty will show the text "Select Logo" and after dbl click event and image selected it will show the image

in this pic box when it is empty it shows no image data I want to display Select logo text

Comment: What project template did you use WinForm or WPF or something else? Maybe you can update your question with more details and then i can help in here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify If you're working with WinForm or WPF so update the question as soon as you can, to resolve this one you can probably do something like this:

```
If(pictureBox.Image == null)
{
    pictureBox.Text = "Select Logo";
}
```

This should do the work for you, let me know if I understood the question the right way